# Two different values for the same day when calculating max_over_time over two different time ranges

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am tracking the number of jobs in a queue at specific time intervals using a gauge metric. Prometheus scrapes this every minute.

However, when I attempt to determine the highest number of jobs in the queue on a given day using the max_over_time query, I receive two distinct values for the same day based on different time ranges.

I am using the query `max_over_time(job_count_by_service{service="ServiceA", tenant="TenantA"}[1d])`. When I run this query for a 1-day time range (from 2023-08-19 00:00:00 to 2023-08-19 23:59:59), the value I get is 38. However, when I run the same query for a 5-day time range (from 2023-08-18 00:00:00 to 2023-08-22 23:59:59), the result for Aug 19th is 35.

2023-08-19 00:00:00 to 2023-08-19 23:59:59
[image: Value Screenshot1]

2023-08-18 00:00:00 to 2023-08-22 23:59:59
[image: Value Screenshot2]

In Grafana I have configured the Min Step as 1d and Type as Range. I'm not sure whether that could affect the values in any way.

I assumed that max_over_time would pick the max value among all the values that fall in the range vector specified time period. For example, if on Day 1 the values are [1,2,7,6,5] and on Day 2 the values are [8,1,2,3,1] then the query would return 7 & 8 respectively for each day.

Comment: Have you used the same query in both cases?

Comment: Also, not that it matter to this question, but I think you are wrong about dates. If I understand what is shown on first screenshot correctly it is not 2023-08-**19** 00:00:00 to 2023-08-**19** 23:59:59, but 2023-08-**18** 00:00:00 to 2023-08-**18** 23:59:59

Comment: @markalex I used the same query for both cases and selected a time interval of 2023-08-19 00:00:00 to 2023-08-19 23:59:59 in Grafana. However, the value 38 is from the metrics of 2023-08-18 00:00:00 to 2023-08-18 23:59:59, as you pointed out.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Your assumptions are correct, and it's in fact how `max_over_time` works. Maybe some edge cases are at play here. Please consider running `curl 'https://loclhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=max_over_time(job_count_by_service{service="ServiceA", tenant="TenantA"}[1d])&start=2023-08-17T00:00:00Z&end=2023-08-22T23:59:59Z&step=1d'` (but replace localhost with address of your Prometheus), and same for `start=2023-08-19T00:00:00Z&end=2023-08-19T23:59:59Z`

Comment: To exclude any possible effect of Grafana from this problem.

Comment: @markalex Let me try it out. The environment where Prometheus is deployed has access restrictions so please expect some delay for the next update.

Answer (score 1):

The [max_over_time(m[d])](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#max_over_time) returns the maximum value for every time series matching `m` [series selector](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering) on the time range `(t-d ... t]`, where `t` is the timestamp where the query is calculated. For example, if  `t=2023-08-19` and `d=1d`, then the query returns the maximum sample value per each matching time series on the time range `(2023-08-18T00:00:00.000 ... 2023-08-19T00:00:00.000]`. Note that the first millisecond at `2023-08-18` isn't included in the time range, while the first millisecond at `2023-08-19` is included in the time range.
Basically, `max_over_time(m[1d])` returns the maximum sample value over the previous 24 hours ending at the requested timestamp. If you want returning the maximum value over the next 24 hours starting from the requested timestamp, then the [offset](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) modifier can be used. For example, the following query returns the max sample value over the next 24 hours starting from the requested timestamp:

```
max_over_time(m[1d] offset -1d)
```

Comment: By using offset we can change the time interval that is being considered but my question is how the max value can change for the same query. To elaborate when I select 2023-08-19 00:00:00 to 2023-08-19 23:59:59 as the time range the values from 2023-08-18T00:00:00.000 ... 2023-08-19T00:00:00.000 is considered to pick a maximum. When I select the time range 2023-08-18 00:00:00 to 2023-08-22 23:59:59 won't the same values again be considered for picking the maximum since the range vector is 1d? So how can the value change from 38 to 35?

Comment: Probably, the max value has the timestamp `2023-08-18T00:00:00.000`, so it is included in the results of the first query on time range `(2023-08-17T23:59:59 ... 2023-08-18T23:59:59]`, while it isn't included in results for the second query because of query timestamp shifted by one second (or millisecond).

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce what your problem at all, so this can only be a partial answer. This would have been a comment, asking you for more information, but one can only comment after getting reputation via answering questions, so here we go.

What prometheus does is select a time-range of 1d - but it's not clear to me how exactly that time range is chosen - it might be 1d from the last data point on and you might have a datapoint at 2023-08-20 00:00:00

max_over_time in https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/promql/functions.go indeed just selects the largest value of all values.

What you should do:
plot/print *all* values of

> job_count_by_service{service="ServiceA", tenant="TenantA"}
> by giving an explicit small "min step" or maybe even choosing a smaller time range to avoid any implicit averaging that might happen. You can limit the amount of output by only looking at large values, e.g.by selecting all values over 34 (if those are integers, else above 34.9):

> job_count_by_service{service="ServiceA", tenant="TenantA"} >34

Then have a look at the beginning and end of the day - or rather at your maximum and why it may be different.

There seems to be a bug, where grafana plots only half the time-span specified.
This can be seen e.g. here in a test plot that I made with grafana:

[image]

The yellow curve are the raw values of the metric, the green line is max_over_time[4m]. The dots are points at which values exist.
The yellow curve goes down from 160 to 158 at 19:48:10, the green line with the max_over_time[4m] decreases value at 19:50:10, 2 minutes later.

When you request a time span of "1d" and have a range from 1s less than 1d, you are cutting values off, which would easily explain that you get a lower value on the shortened timespan, but not a larger value. You additionally have a min step of 1d, which hides most values.

Please include graphs showing the full raw data and the full curve of 1d max_over_time - if at all possible with a sample of a much shorter timespan (or how often do you collect the metric?), then I may be able to complete the answer.

Comment: Are sure about this part "There seems to be a bug..."? Can you reproduce this on play.grafana.com and share a link?

Comment: Also, specifying min step doesn't ensure use of that step: Grafana is free to use bigger steps. To ensure no points are omitted one needs to query data straight from Prometheus.